# How do I commit a Vapor project to GitHub?

Tags: git, github, vapor

I'm getting started with `Vapor` and created a new `hello-world` Vapor project. However if I want to commit this project to my GitHub repo using GitHub Desktop, I don't really see any files to commit even though the project contains a fair few.
[image]

[image]

Is this expected? Making a simple change in the `routes.swift` file shows an untracked change in Xcode but Github desktop doesn't show the changed file. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot, it's because you've got a git repo in a git repo. If you'd open the `hello-world` folder in Github Desktop, you'll see the changes in your repo.

Comment: If I create & checkout a github repository on my machine into a folder & then create a new vapor project in that folder it doesn't show in git source control

Comment: So what I ended up doing is (1.) once the vapor project was created, I added it as a local repo & then published it to GitHub. (2.) Then I moved all the files into a folder called `Server` within the same directory & created another folder `Client` at the same level as `Server` and pushed them to GitHub. I feel there's got to be an easier way to do it?

Comment: So with the approach above I'm still left with the hidden .dockerignore, .gitignore & .git folders in the original vapor project setup that I have no idea what to do with? Do I just delete them? and create them when I need them?

Comment: The Vapor Template is set up by cloning the template repo. So when you create your own repo, and create the template within that, that causes a nested repo. To solve this, either copy the files over yourself - or you'll have to create the repo and start anew with a clean git history in the repo created by the CLI.